# Swift3 - Http GET request not being sent and response not being returned

Tags: ios, http, swift3, get

Im trying to send a http GET request to the server yet it never returns a response and I don't even know if the request is being sent at all.

This is very weird because I know the same code (despite the link) works for another GET request where the server returns a perfect status code 200.

My friend is running the server side code, and says that everything is setup for my request. He thinks it some rogue request that for some reason the server is never getting.

here is the client/request side code:

```
func imageRequest(){

    let imagedata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "micro")!)
    guard let url = URL(string: "myurl") else{ return }
    print(url) //test
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            print(data)
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json  {
                    let status = (parseJSON["status"] as? String)!
                    print("status: \(String(describing: status))")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

even the `print(url)` as a test never executes when the function is called.

Any ideas why it might be doing this?

Comment: There can be many problems from server side, or even from your network. First, try to replace "myurl" with "google.com" to see if your code will execute properly, then check with your friend to dive deeper.

Comment: If your `print`command isn't executed, the error must occur in the two lines before. 1. Your URL is definitely wrong, and your guard statement fails. ;) 2. Loading an image from file and convert it to PNG could be very inefficient, if the file is already a PNG.

Comment: It could be because your method is not getting called. If it is then you must have problem with your url.

Comment: @Jeamz  you have to add AppTransport Security in Xcode in the info.plist file : Refer this link : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3544

Comment: @hoangCap I need to note that I am sending a png picture to my friends server, but I changed the url and sent a normal request to google and it worked fine.

Comment: @macmoonshine I think your right about the URL, also if I am sending image that's already a PNG would i just do `let imagedata = String(describing: UIImage(named: "micro"))` instead, without the PNGRepresentation?

Comment: No, definitely not! `UIImage(named: "micro")` loads an image from disk. This image has a representation. If the representation is PNG, you should load the image data with `NSData(contentsOf:)` or `NSData(contentsOfFile:)`. You can construct the url or path, resp. with `NSBundle`.

Comment: @macmoonshine ok thanks because it was just a string of something like this, "<UIImage 60000800> {657, 423}